# i keep getting the error on xamarin studio that tells me the dll.mdb is missing. Isnt it supposed to be automatically generated? How do i fix this?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\Tolu\Documents\ICE
>   Dialler\Dialler1\Dialler1\Dialler1\bin\Debug\Dialler1.dll.mdb" because
>   it was not found. (MSB3030) (Dialler1)

Comment: Try to build DLL only before you build the app project. This error may mean that the dll cannot be build because of errors and then obviously it cannot be copied.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: Isnt there a way the project can generate the dll.mdb file automatically

Comment: do you have any other errors when you build?

Comment: Xamarin Studio is considered obsolete on Windows. Please use Visual Studio.

Comment: Nope that's the only one.

Comment: I would but i keep getting this error when i try to install vs 2017. Error 0x80131509: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)The specified instance '71ccf5c6' cannot be installed to the same location or child directory of existing instance '79003c0b'